# CakePHP does not store the created date on live server

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have exactly the same scripts and exactly same databases running on localhost and on live server. The problem I face is that the date for 'created' is not automatically stored.

Here is the controller action:

```
function add() {
    if (!empty($this->data) ) {
        $this->Customer->create();
        if ($this->Customer->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Customer was saved'), 'positive_notification');
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'customers', 'action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Customer was not saved. Please try again'), 'negative_notification');
        }
    }
}
```

There is also no function for beforeSave.

And here is the database table:

```
`customers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customer_nr` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_nr` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `color` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `created` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `company_id` (`company_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=113 ;
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try changing `created` from 'date' to 'datetime'

Comment: Did that already, with no luck.

Comment: Your sample code is incomplete! You have relation between models and you trying to save data to different tables?

Comment: Sorry, there was no beforeSave function in the customer model. So the code is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use:

```
     $this->request->data //instead of $this->data
```

But if the **created** is the only field that is not saved try to debug first the **$this->data** then try this first to see if its really saving a data:

```
   $this->data["Customer"]["created"] = data("Y-m-d"); // temporarily set to current date just to see if it was saving
   $this->Customer->save($this->data)
```

Then checked if its added on your database. If yes, then you must update your **$this->data**, it may contain **incorrect values** or **incorrect format of date**.

Answer (score 0):

The date is not automatically updating, because you set `created` to be `date` instead of `datetime`.

As stated on "[Saving Your Data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#using-created-and-modified)"

> By defining a created and/or modified field in your database table as datetime fields (default null), CakePHP will recognize those fields and populate them automatically whenever a record is created or saved to the database (unless the data being saved already contains a value for these fields).

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I have changed that to datetime. Now I have to exact scripts running with exact the same databases but one just would sotre the created date.